# ReactNative 0.43-rc.2 -- android Image inline resize

Tags: react-native

I just upgraded to version 0.43-rc.2 in order to get `FlatList` support, but now on Android, my `<Image>` that is inline inside of a `<Text>` isn't resizing the content to fit the `height` and `width` I have set in the properties. In previous versions, I had to set `resizeMethod="scale"` in order to get this to work, but that property seems to have no effect now.

Any Ideas what to do to get this working?

Comment: According to docs resizeMethod expects either of `'auto', 'resize', 'scale'`

Comment: oops, 'scale' is what I had it set to, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue detected on react-native v0.44.2. 
I fixed it multipliying by PixelRatio on Android.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logo: {
    width: 25 * (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 1 : PixelRatio.get()),
    height: 14 * (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 1 : PixelRatio.get())
  }
});
```

I found the solution on: https://gist.github.com/yloeza/2d250060db023127a4654c35f2c37ec8